# Command raised an exception: KeyError: '248120040153415681'

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, keyerror

I made a Discord Bot who gives esperience and lvl to user. I want to add +rank in order to see what rank the user is and how much he has on exp. Now i tried coding it but i get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fggLy.png)

and this is my code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2GdV.png)

my json file is named expe.

[whole experience code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tKuIr.png)

Comment: You're using `[user.id + "-" + server.id]` everywhere else.  Why are you just using `[user.id]` in `rank`?

Comment: Please update your question to directly include both the code and the traceback or your error. Basically you need to provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can you put your code in your question as text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you use the rewrite version of discord.py, so you have to access it with `[str(user.id)]` because IDs are now integers and keys of dictionaries in JSON must always be strings.